# Python Text room based game

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, error-handling, computer-science

Need help in adjusting my code, i am unable to move to other room, i can only move North and south no other room is being recognized. the goal is to be able to go back and forth between the rooms. Rooms in use are as followed : Attic, Living Room, Foyer, Front Porch, Bedroom, Basement, Kitchen, Dinning Room.

I would like to figure out a way to solve the current code so it doesn't loop, is there a statement i can add so it can go back and forth between rooms ? I'd like to try an figure out a way to keep this code with out altering it too much for the sake of knowledge.

The Design pattern is as followed: ( Starting out in the Attic)

Attic (Start) - Go South to Living Room

Living Room - Go West to Dining Room, North back to Attic, East to Foyer

Foyer - Go West to Living Room, North to Bedroom, South to Front Porch

Bedroom - Go south to Foyer

Front Porch - Go North to Foyer

dining Room - Go East to Living Room, North to Kitchen, South to Basement

Kitchen - Go South to Dining Room

Basement - Go North to Dining Room

My Code is as Followed :

```
     rooms = {
'Attic': {'South': ' Living Room'},

'Living Room': {'East': 'Foyer', 'West': 'Dining Room','North': 'Attic'},
      
'Foyer': {'North': 'Bedroom', 'South': 'Front Porch', 'West': 'Living Room'},
     
'Bedroom': {'South': 'Foyer'},
    
'Dining Room': {'East': 'Living Room', 'North': 'Kitchen', 'South': 'Basement'},
     
'Kitchen': {'South': 'Dining Room'},
     
'Basement': {'North': 'Dining Room'},
    
'Front Porch': {'North': 'Foyer'},
    
}

def possible_moves():
  moves = rooms[location].keys()
  print("Option:", *moves)

location = 'Attic'

Direction = ''

while True:
  print('You are in the', location)

  possible_moves()

  direction = input("Which way would you like to go? ")

  if direction == 'Exit' or Direction == 'exit':

    print('Thank you for playing!')
    break
  elif direction == 'South' or direction == 'south':
      location = 'Living Room'
      print('You are in the', location)

      possible_moves()

      direction = input("Which way would you like to go? ")

      if direction == 'East' or direction == 'east':

        location = 'Foyer'
        print('You are in the', location)
        possible_moves()
        direction = input("Which way would you like to go? ")

  elif direction == 'North' or direction == 'north':

        location = 'Attic'
        print('You are in the', location)
        possible_moves()
        direction = input("Which way would you like to go? ")

  else:
   print('Invalid')
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess this should do what you want:

```
ROOMS = {'Attic': {'South': 'Living Room'},
     'Living Room': {'East': 'Foyer', 'West': 'Dining Room','North': 'Attic'},
     'Foyer': {'North': 'Bedroom', 'South': 'Front Porch', 'West': 'Living Room'},
     'Bedroom': {'South': 'Foyer'},
     'Dining Room': {'East': 'Living Room', 'North': 'Kitchen', 'South': 'Basement'},
     'Kitchen': {'South': 'Dining Room'},
     'Basement': {'North': 'Dining Room'},
     'Front Porch': {'North': 'Foyer'},
}

location = 'Attic'
while True:
    print(f'You are in {location}')
    print('Options:', *ROOMS[location].keys(), 'Exit')  # print the possible moves
    direction = input('Which way would you like to go? ').capitalize()
    if direction == 'Exit':
        break
    try:
        location = ROOMS[location][direction]
    except KeyError:
        print('Invalid')
```

Comment: Please explain the problem and its solution instead of just dumping some code